# Reference Parent Object in Apex

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have a custom object set up within Salesforce called Solar_Install. I have a S2S connection with another installation of Salesforce. I want to share the custom object with them as well as the parent object (Account), partly because child objects inherit the autoshare property from their parent so I have to.

I have an Apex trigger on the child object (the Solar_Install) which looks like this:

```
trigger shareWithPartner on Solar_Install__c (after insert) {

PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newConnection =
                new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection(
                    ConnectionId = '12AB3456789CDEF',
                    LocalRecordId = trigger.new[0].id,
                    SendClosedTasks = false,
                    SendOpenTasks = false,
                    SendEmails = false,
                    ParentRecordId = ???);
insert newConnection;
}
```

but I don't know what to put in for the ??? value. I have tried various things:

trigger.new[0].Account_c.AccountId

Error: Compile Error: Invalid foreign key relationship: Solar_Install__c.Account_c at line 10 column 57

Account_c

Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Account_c at line 10 column 42

etc. Does anyone know how I reference the parent (Account) Id from this custom object in order that I can specify it as the ParentRecordId?

Cheers

Comment: Did you try traversing the Account relationship with `Account__r.Id` or `Account__c` (with two underscores)? These should be the same, but the latter would preferred because it doesn't require a join.

Comment: Hi. Yes, for each of those I get a Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Account__c... In the object definition there is Master-Detail(Account) with an API name of Account__c and field label of Account

Comment: got it. needed to reference the custom object too. This worked.  ParentRecordId = trigger.new[0].Account__c Post your comment as an answer and I'll mark it as such

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try traversing the Account relationship with Account_*r.Id or Account*_c (with two underscores)? These should be the same, but the latter would preferred because it doesn't require a join.